# How to ensure Python’s asyncio library executes tasks in depth first search order

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I’d like to spawn tasks and make sure they are started in depth first order. Example code:

```
import asyncio

async def level_three(i, j):
    print(f'level three, node {i} {j}')
    asyncio.sleep(0)

async def level_two(i):
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(level_three(i, j)) for j in range(2)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print(f'level two, node {i}')

async def level_one():
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(level_two(i)) for i in range(2)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print('level one')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(level_one())
```

Output:

```
level three, node 0 0
level three, node 0 1
level three, node 1 0
level three, node 1 1
level two, node 0
level two, node 1
level one
```

Instead I’d like to write the code so that the second two level threes are printed after the first level two.

Effectively I want to say: launch this thread until it sleeps, then launch the second one, etc

Thanks!

Comment: That seems to defeat the purpose of the whole *async* thing. Why are you using asyncio at all?

Comment: I want to be using async because in the backend each of my functions is doing asynchronous operations on a compute cluster. But I want to launch those operations on the cluster in a particular order because it makes debugging much easier. I use async to await all the cluster jobs at the same time while they’re running simultaneously.

Comment: Populate your list of tasks recursively?

Comment: My computational structure is inherently a DAG, which means I do already populate the list recursively